# Why JLupin Storage Queue cannot access task?

Tags: java, application-server

I've encountered problem using JLupin Storage Queue.
It has problems retrieving task when finished.
JLupin is configured on 2 clusters, 3 servers each. Jlupin QueueMicroservice is installed on each of them.
Thank you in advance.

```
    2019-02-11 11:31:33,403 | Error | pool-4-thread-483 |  | com.jlupin.impl.processor.strategy.impl.JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorInvokeStrategyImpl | MESSAGE ID:1 SESSION ID:8559396366643622404 REQUEST ID:5589808491859060249 METHOD:invoke LINE:136 LOG:an error in JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorImpl occurred caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2019-02-11 11:31:33,409 | Error | pool-4-thread-483 |  | com.jlupin.impl.entrypoint.microservice.queue.JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl$3 | MESSAGE ID:5 METHOD:call LINE:681 LOG:an error occurred during executing task described by session id:8559396366643622404 and request id:5589808491859060249 caused by:
com.jlupin.interfaces.client.delegator.exception.JLupinDelegatorException: an unexpected error occurred during communication caused by:
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:738) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.access$3200(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:32) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl$10.call(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:640) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.helper.repeater.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorRepeaterHelper.doWithRepeat(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorRepeaterHelper.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.doPutTaskResultCommunicationWrappedSequence(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:637) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.delegate(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:79) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.entrypoint.microservice.queue.JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl$3.call(JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.java:672) [?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.entrypoint.microservice.queue.JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl$3.call(JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.java:629) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: com.jlupin.interfaces.balancer.exception.JLupinLoadBalancerException: balancer type:INNER_MICROSERVICE can not send request for repeats amount:4 to any servers caused by:
        at com.jlupin.impl.balancer.ext.impl.repeat.JLupinAbstractRepeatLoadBalancer.executeBalanceCommunication(JLupinAbstractRepeatLoadBalancer.java:65) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:649) ~[?:?]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.exception.JLupinDelegatorWithPossibleRepeatException: an unexpected error (with possible to repeat) occurred during during executing doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence function described by session id:8559396366643622404 and request id:5589808491859060249 caused by:
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl$11.doCommunication(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:723) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.balancer.base.JLupinBaseLoadBalancer.executeBalanceCommunicationInternal(JLupinBaseLoadBalancer.java:619) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.balancer.ext.impl.repeat.JLupinAbstractRepeatLoadBalancer.executeBalanceCommunication(JLupinAbstractRepeatLoadBalancer.java:38) ~[?:?]
        at com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.balance.JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence(JLupinQueueLoadBalancerDelegatorImpl.java:649) ~[?:?]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.jlupin.impl.client.delegator.exception.JLupinDelegatorWithPossibleRepeatException: an error occurred during executing doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence caused by:com.jlupin.interfaces.microservice.partofjlupin.asynchronous.service.queue.exception.JLupinQueueManagerServiceException: an error occurred during saving task:BOSGW-APB01{$}SIA_LOG{$}1{$}7164689466323701{$}816cf1fd-9e51-4227-a66e-8e0ff911fbaf8974513202941020_DISK result caused by:
        at com.jlupin.impl.microservice.partofjlupin.asynchronous.service.impl.queue.JLupinDefaultQueueManagerServiceImpl.putTaskResultAsException(JLupinDefaultQueueManagerServiceImpl.java:200)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.jlupin.impl.util.JLupinUtil.invokeMethod(JLupinUtil.java:215)
        at com.jlupin.impl.processor.strategy.impl.JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorInvokeStrategyImpl.invoke(JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorInvokeStrategyImpl.java:126)
        at com.jlupin.impl.processor.JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorImpl.invoke(JLupinDefaultServiceProcessorImpl.java:51)
        at com.jlupin.impl.entrypoint.microservice.queue.JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.doPutTaskResultCommunicationSequence(JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.java:827)
        at com.jlupin.impl.entrypoint.microservice.queue.JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.doEntry(JLupinQueueMicroserviceEntryPointImpl.java:184)
        at com.jlupin.impl.server.jnative.defaults.strategy.service.base.JLupinBaseAbstractServiceStrategy$ThreadCallable.call(JLupinBaseAbstractServiceStrategy.java:204)
        at com.jlupin.impl.server.jnative.defaults.strategy.service.base.JLupinBaseAbstractServiceStrategy$ThreadCallable.call(JLupinBaseAbstractServiceStrategy.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably didn't configured shared disk for your queueMicroservice's instances. By default "platform/storage" is used as a location for storing queue's data. Check JLupin's documentation for more details about configuring queues with disk storage implementation.

https://jlupin.io/documentation/jlupin-reactive-queues-16/page/storage-jlupin_disk.html